# Rss and Javascript, parsing and displaying a feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

I am trying to pull an RSS feed, in this case http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk, and display it in some css designed cards, kind of like a news feed, in the divcontainer element on my page. I have tried several options like feednami, jFeed etc, and not managed to get anything to work. I have included an example of my code below to better illustrate what I mean and the information I need to pull, it sounds like there is a very simple answer to this but I havent been able to find one. I understand that the google feeds API would previously have been good for this but is now deprecated, does this mean I shouldn't use it?

```
// URL of feed to pull, and integer specifying how many items to pull from that feed
var feedURL = ;
var noOfItems = 20;

// In the 2D array of items we will store [0]Title, [1]Link, [2]Description/Text, [3]Source (this will be used in a later version to specify image
// in this iteration source will always be BBC so have hardcoded image) [4]Date (displayable format) [5]Date in milliseconds to be used in a later iteration
// [6]Image path (to be calculated from source, for now i have simply hardcoded the image path for the bbc logo, but eventualy will implement an array of
// feedURLs, and a switch statement to assign each source the correct logo)
var feedItems = new Array(noOfItems);
for (var i = 0; i < feedItems.length; i++) {
  x[i] = new Array(6);
}
// ----------------------- Pull Rss Feed -------------------------------------//
// Have no idea how to implement this now, have tried jFeed, and Feednami, could get neither to work
// looked into doing it myself but came across issues with javascript ecurity and the feed needing to be from the same url



//-------------------------- Creating Card on News Feed ---------------------//
// This feature could probably be made into a function? taking input of the variables below?
// Not entirely sure how best to implement this until i know how to pull the info from the xml feed
var itemtitle;
var itemlink;
var itemtext;
var itemimage = 'img/sources/bbc.png';
var itemdate;

var itemcard;   

itemcard = '<div id=card>';
itemcard += '<img src=';

itemcard += itemimage;

itemcard += ' id=cardimg>';
itemcard += '<a href=';

itemcard += itemlink;

itemcard += ' id=cardlink><h1 id=cardhead>';

itemcard += itemtitle;

itemcard += '</h1></a>';
itemcard += '<h4 id=cardinfo>';

itemcard += itemdate;

itemcard += '</h4>';
itemcard += '<p id=cardtext>';

itemcard += itemtext;

itemcard += '</p>';
itemcard += '</div>';



$('#feedcontainer').append(itemcard);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can do it using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But, you should be aware of cross-domain problems you might face.

Comment: So this would open the feed, how would i then get the individual aspects of each item to store in my array? something like

feedItems[0][0] = title; 
feedItems[0][1] = link etc,

May i also ask what you mean by cross domain problems, I have heard mention that this is an issue, would it be an issue in this case, as naturally my site will not be on the bbc domain

with the code you have supplied. how do i then go about parsing the feed?

Comment: You can follow up [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) for parsing XML using jQuery and read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on Wikipedia for the cross-origin issue.